# { Spawn } vs spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, child-process

I came across this while learning about child processes:

```js
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
```

My question is, what is the difference between the above and this:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **1st** extracts `spawn` variable from inside `child_proccess`.
This only unpack value of `spawn` from `child_proccess` instead of the whole module.

The **2nd** sets `spawn` variable the entire `child_process` module (as a whole).

[read more on Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)